# Change placeholder last letter color

Tags: html, css

Example code: `<input type="text" placeholder="Fast name *">`

I want to change the color on the placeholder last letter, in this case, " * ", but I need a solution with CSS, I don't need a javascript solution.  I display the string letter by letter and I can't use a static solution.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do that with CSS alone

Answer (score -3):

only type in css input[type=text]::placeholder and note that which placeholder you want to change the color and other write the type in attribute selector.
Thanks

Comment: But he wants last letter, not whole placeholder.

Comment: He looking for * only not whole text